# How to stream Ip camera live feed in my web application using rtsp link ,which created in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically, i Want to show the live feed of my IP camera on web page
I am a full fresher

```
try to use nuget package manager
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the Video element

```
<video autoplay></video>
```

and some java script to get that

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
function hasGetUserMedia() {
   return !!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}

if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
    const constraints = {
        video: true
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
            then((stream) => { video.srcObject = stream; video.play(); }).catch((err) => { alert(err.message);});
} else {
    alert('Video capture is not supported by your browser');
}
```